# Difference between REST and POX

Tags: web-services, rest, pox

I really can't get the difference between REST and POX web services. I mean, couldn't POX be considered as a REST web service with XML message definitions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on what your "Plain Old XML" contains.

The thing is, POX used to be compared with SOAP. SOAP is a very specific way to do XML over (mostly) HTTP and people were already doing "plain old XML" over HTTP. SOAP got  a lot of criticism because it complicated the things people were already doing with POX. But I won't go into that, what I'm trying to say is that people used POX to do [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call).

REST isn't RPC. In REST, the XML is a representation of a resource, not a message definition as in RPC. There is also a very important REST constraint that people seem to forget or ignore that imposes constraints on the returned XML: [the hypermedia constraint or HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS).

If you want to find out more about how POX fits in REST, I recommend reading this article: [Richardson Maturity Model, steps toward the glory of REST](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html).